# How to Display total mysql queries executed specific mysqli class

Tags: php, php-mysqlidb

I am using this php class. here it is https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class

Could someone tell me how I can get the number of queries that have been run during a trace session. The trace documentation is at the end of the documentation page on github.

Comment: Do you mean this section of the Documentation `Query exectution time benchmarking`?

Comment: Then just do a `count($db->trace);` to get the number of queries you have executed. Of course you will have to set `$db->setTrace (true);` to get it to start logging

Comment: Oh thank you so much @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this documentation, each trace is stored in the object as an array see `print_r ($db->trace);` at the end.

```
Query exectution time benchmarking

To track query execution time setTrace() function should be called.

$db->setTrace (true);
// As a second parameter it is possible to define prefix of the path which should be striped from filename
// $db->setTrace (true, $_SERVER['SERVER_ROOT']);
$db->get("users");
$db->get("test");
print_r ($db->trace);

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => SELECT  * FROM t_users ORDER BY `id` ASC
            [1] => 0.0010669231414795
            [2] => MysqliDb->get() >>  file "/avb/work/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/tests.php" line #151
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => SELECT  * FROM t_test
            [1] => 0.00069189071655273
            [2] => MysqliDb->get() >>  file "/avb/work/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/tests.php" line #152
        )
```

So you can get the number of queries executed by just doing

```
$num = count($db->trace);
```

Comment: Lol i saw it now. Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure completely